# find student numbers of students who take all courses in department 'CS'

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra, relational-division

```
students (sid, sname)
courses (cid, cname, dept)
take (sid, cid, grade)
```

We want to find student numbers of students who take all courses in department 'CS'.

Why is line 4 the answer?

How does it differ from lines 1 through 3?

I read this in Solved-Ex in DB.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to phrase the fourth line is:

```
all students
except
(
    all combinations of students and CS courses
    except
    all taken courses
)
```

The set between brackets contains all student + CS course combinations that were not taken.  Subtract this from all students, and you get the students that did take all CS exams.