# Complex Relational Algebra?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, relational-algebra

We have 3-Relation:

```
Students(sid, sname)
Courses(cid, cname, dept)
take(sid, cid, grade)
```

Who Can Describe these relational algebra for me?

[image]

Is equivalent to second one:
[image]

Comment: Re downvotes please read the mouseover for the icon.

Comment: Even if you assigned it as homework for yourself, it's still homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942035/relational-algebra-and-confusing-one-complex-examples .

Comment: http://www6.sanjesh.org/download/arshad94q/513-c.pdf  please see page 11 @philipxy

Comment: An Introduction to Database Systems (8th Edition): C.J. Date @philipxy

Comment: Interesting: The question notation is from some other source than your textbook. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is incorrect or undefined, according to the definition of most popular database books, since the second operand of the division should have attributes that are a subset of the attributes of the first operand (*this first paragraph has been edited according to the comments below*).

The second expression is a regular division that returns the `sid` of the students that have taken *all* the courses of 'CS'.

The third expression first calculates the cartesian product of all the `sid` of students with the `cid` of all the 'CS' courses, and from those set removes *all* the pairs `(sid,cid)` present in `take`. So, at the end, the set will contains the couples `sid`, `cid` where `sid` identifies a student a `cid` a 'CS' course *not* taken by that student. Finally this set is projected over `sid`, so that this expression returns all the students that did not taken *all* the 'CS' courses. In other words, the *complement* of the second expression.

*Edited*

The fourth expression *is* equivalent to the second one, and this is very easy to prove: consider that this expression is simply equal to:

π<sub>sid</sub>(students) - (the third expression)

and since the third expression returns the `sid` of all the students that did not taken all the 'CS' courses, subtracting this set from the `sid` of all the students we found again all (and only) the students that have taken *all* the 'CS' course. In other words, the complement of the complement, i.e. the original set obtained by the division, that is the second expression.

Comment: Sorry I add another picture. how this is possible that the new picture is equivalent to second one ? it's complex fomula.

Comment: @LoveComplexity & Renzo Wikipedia is wrong. Codd's division R / S is defined on all pairs of relations & gives the same answer as for R / π common attributes (S). (See his [Relational Completeness paper](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/III/lehre/vorlesungen/Informationssysteme/WS05/materialien/Codd72a.pdf).) Date misunderstood and popularized the version with attributes of R a superset of S's. (See his [Database Explorations book Division chapter](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Database-Explorations-revision-2.pdf).) Definitions ok for Date's are not always ok for Codd's. So 1st = 2nd.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks, this is very interesting, at least from historical point of view. However I think that the Date definition is what is used in current database courses, as a lot of database books testify, for instance: Molina-Ullman-Widom, Database Systems, 2nd ed, p.58; Ramakrishnan-Gehrke, Database Management Systems, 3rd ed., p.109; Silberschatz-Korth-Sundarshan Database System Concepts, 6th ed., p.250; Connolly-Bag, Database Systems, 4th ed., p.150; Abiteboul-Hull-Vianu, Foundations of Databases, 1995, p.99; Elmasri-Navathe, Fundamentals of Database Systems, 6th ed., p.163.

Comment: @Renzo But the 1st expression has S's header *not* a subset of R's. So it is not using Date's version. And all those references, defining the Date version, like it are *undefined* in this case. Only Wikipedia allows for arbitrary relations, Codd's version, and it is confused. The actual reason why "it is usually required that the attribute names in the header of S are a subset of those of R" is it's Date's version. Not "because otherwise the result of the operation will always be empty" with Codd's version, because it won't. Rather, when there are no common attributes then the result is empty.

Comment: @philipxy ok, thanks again, I will rephrase my answer, and so, maybe, you should consider correcting the Wikipedia page?

Comment: Isn't the second one "all sid that have taken the course of CS"? rather than "the sid of the students that have taken all the courses of 'CS'." Maybe it is the same, I'm not native...

Comment: @Marine1, 'CS' is a department (for instance, Computer Science), that has many courses... So the query is "all sid that have taken *all* the courses of that department". This is the idea of the division operator, which has relation with the universal quantifier "all" (you can see this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34979122/2382734), for instance).

Comment: @Marine1 & Renzo: Actually division returns students who have taken all the courses of that department *and have taken at least one course*. The difference is, if that department doesn't offer any courses then students that have taken all the courses of that department include the students who have taken no courses but division doesn't.